# Can I access the inherent provider built in a factory?

Tags: angularjs

I have a situation were I would love to access a .factory('Auth') in my code in my angular.module(...).config() call.  Now I realize that the .factory('Auth') is not a provider and so it cannot be accessed.  Yet I also know that there is internally a provider created for this .factory('Auth').  So is there an easy was to either:

```
1. Convert a factory -> provider and then use the factory portion later as I currently use 'Auth'?
2. get access to the provider from the factory name 'Auth' so that I can simply pass it into .config()?
```

I sort of know angular as a user without knowing the internals and would love to solve this problem easily.  You insight greatly appreciated!

This question came up because I have an app that uses the 'textAngular' module and it is configured to provide control buttons as a part of the UI during the .config() phase.  For example:

```
$provide.decorator('taOptions', ['taRegisterTool', '$delegate', function(taRegisterTool, taOptions){

       taRegisterTool('addImage', {
          display: '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default ng-scope" title="Add Images Remote">' +
         '<div class="addImage hideElement" ng-app="tracker2App" ' +
         'ng-controller="FilesCtrl" ngf-select ' +
         'addfile type="button" ng-model="images" ' +
         'ngf-multiple="true" ngf-allow-dir="false" + 
         'accept="image/*"' +
         'ngf-keep="true" ngf-keep-distinct="true" ' +
         'ngf-reset-on-click="resetOnClick" ngf-reset-model-on-click="resetModelOnClick"></div>' +
            '<span><i class="fa fa-file-image-o"></i><i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i></span></button>',
      action: function (deferred) {
        var self = this;
        $('.addImage.hideElement').click();
        self.deferred = deferred;
        self.type='image';
        return false;
      },
      addItems: function (files, passedScope) {
        if (files) {
        var embed='';
        let bResetImages=true;
        files.forEach(function(file) {
          if (bResetImages) {
            embed += '<img src="' + file.url + '" style="width:100%;">';
          } else {
            embed += '<img src="' + file.url + '">';
          }
        });
        this.$editor().wrapSelection('insertHTML', embed);
      }
      if (typeof passedScope.$$childHead.deferred !== 'undefined') {
        passedScope.$$childHead.deferred.resolve();
      }
    }
  });
  taOptions.toolbar[3].splice(4,0, 'addImage');

}]);
```

And I need to be able to change the addItems: function(..) to be:

```
      addItems: function (files, passedScope) {
        if (files) {
        var embed='';
        let bResetImages=Auth.getCurrentUser().options.bResetImageSize;
        files.forEach(function(file) {
          if (bResetImages) {
            embed += '<img src="' + file.url + '" style="width:100%;">';
          } else {
            embed += '<img src="' + file.url + '">';
          }
        });
```

So that the currentUser.options can be accessed later by textAngular when the user adds an image.  I hope this makes it clearer.

In the end I solved this by modifying the addItems() function above and passing as a third argument the data I needed.

The key insight was realizing that the 'html' code uses the ng-controller="FilesCtrl" and so it is this controller that calls addItems() and has access to everything I needed.

Thanks again for those that took a look at this question.  When I have more time, I might attempt to do some sort of a hybrid solution to fully answer this question.

Comment: What would you do with that provider? It has a single $get() method, which is used to instantiate the service and is intended to be called by Angular. So there's nothing useful you can do with that provider. What are you trying to achieve? If you need a configurable provider, why don't you define one, instead of using a factory?

Comment: I have a complicated factory('Auth') that has a getCurrentUser() function and I would like to access the currentUser in the code that .config() provides to the textAngular module.    -- It is not that the factory('Auth') needs to be configured, it is simply that I want to get access to the factory in the calls with the code passed back from config().

I will make this more concrete is the question above.

Comment: If by factory, you really mean factory, then this factory should be a provider. If by factory, you men the service creates by the factory, then you can't use if during the config phase. Post your code, and explain what you want to do during the config phase, with code.

Comment: Please see the example above.  I realize that what I first asked wasn't clear.  So in a sense, I want to know if I can access this factory later-- somehow.

Comment: I solved this problem another way and I believe that my original question is a bit wrong-headed.  But thanks very much for your input.  I inspired me to solve this by changing the addItems() function.